# Can we use predicted values for forecasting?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-science, forecasting, forecast

For example, In case of moving average if we are predicting 11th value using the last 10 values so can we use 11th predicted value for predicting the 12th value and so on. If yes can we also apply the same approach for other forecasting models?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about methodology and not programming.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is called recursive forecasting and it is the approach used by most statistical forecasting methods (moving average, ARIMA, Exponential Smoothing, etc...). ML based forecasting methods on the other hand sometimes use recursive forecasting, and sometimes use direct forecasting, where for example you forecast value 15 based directly on value 10 (i.e. you train a different model to forecast value 15 than the one you would use to forecast 11).

See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360283/is-it-wise-to-use-predicted-values-to-model-predicted-values-further-down-the-li/360296#360296) for details.